# Using both Minecraft and Minecraft-Tekkit tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

When I have a question to ask about the Tekkit pack for Minecraft, should I tag my question with both [minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft) and [minecraft-tekkit](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-tekkit) or just [minecraft-tekkit](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-tekkit)? Speaking from my experience with StackOverflow, we specifically discourage tagging both [java](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/java) and [android](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android) in one question, as the question rarely has anything to do with Java itself.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We do tagging a little bit differently, here on Arqade.

The only rule we've been able to consistently agree upon, is that the game the question is about should be one of the tags.

This means that [minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft) && [minecraft-tekkit](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-tekkit) should both be present on a question about the latter, since the base game is minecraft.

An exception is made for mods that drastically alter the gameplay - [dota](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dota) does not require a [wc3-tft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wc3-tft) tag as well, nor does [dayz](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dayz) require [arma-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arma-2).

From my understanding, Tekkit adds a whole lot of stuff onto minecraft, but it's still about placing blocks.

Comment: Ah, once again an opportunity to advertise my [implicit tagging hierarchy feature-request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/58073/146482) :-7